# Programatically fill a nxn matrix with a gaussian filter in C++

Tags: graphics, matrix

I need to fill an nXn matrix with a Gaussian filter programatically. I've been trying to work this out for a graphics project, but i'm a little stuck.

To clarify, an example 3x3 Gaussian filter matrix would be:

`[1, 2, 1]`
`[2, 4, 2]`  / 16.0
`[1, 2, 1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a formula for a 2d gauss kernel and fill in your x and y values.

e.g. symmetric gauss kernel:

```
 double w = exp(-(fx*fx + fy*fy) / (2.0 * sigma * sigma)) / (2.0 * M_PI * sigma * sigma);
```

For an explanation with nice graphs see:

http://www.librow.com/articles/article-9

especially: 3. 2D case

Comment: Note that choice of sigma and gain (particularly for integer coefficients) are quite important, so you might want to add some further detail on how these are determined.

Comment: Yes, that would be very helpful. Not sure what to put my standard deviation at to get 'good' results

Comment: See at http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/image_filtering.html#cv-getgaussiankernel - sigma = 0.3*(ksize/2 - 1) + 0.8 (ksize is the odd length of the edge, 3 in your case)

Comment: Probably the above question was, what would be my sigma if I want a 3x3 kernel that adds up to 1.0 ? With sigma = 0.3*(3/2 - 1) + 0.8, the weights add up to just 0.81 so sigma needs to be smaller, how to determine how much smaller ?